# undefined reference to zmq using Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, zeromq

There are several answers on the internet that I've found regarding this matter, but none of them worked for me(I am using Windows by the way).

this is the hello world server example from zeroMQ's site:

```
//
//  Hello World server in C++
//  Binds REP socket to tcp://*:5555
//  Expects "Hello" from client, replies with "World"
//
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#ifndef _WIN32
#include <unistd.h>
#else
#include <windows.h>

#define sleep(n)    Sleep(n)
#endif

int main () {
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket.bind ("tcp://*:5555");

    while (true) {
        zmq::message_t request;

        //  Wait for next request from client
        socket.recv (&request);
        std::cout << "Received Hello" << std::endl;

        //  Do some 'work'
        sleep(1);

        //  Send reply back to client
        zmq::message_t reply (5);
        memcpy (reply.data (), "World", 5);
        socket.send (reply);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I have the zmq.hpp and I already linked the libzmq.lib on the linker settings(I am using GCC Compiler on Code::Blocks) and I got this error(in zmq.hpp):

Build Messages

[image]

I assume that this has something to do with the library. I've tried:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "libzmq.lib")
```

Comment: How did you build ZMQ binaries (.lib, .dll in case of dynamic linking)? And, how are you linking it? Static or dynamic? Please add your IDE's options for the same with your question.

Comment: The information that may explain your linkage failure will be in the **Build log**, not the **Build messages**, of the failing build. Copy and paste the entire build log, *as text*, not a picture, into the body of your question, instead of the picture of the build messages.